# grep misreads pattern from variable

Tags: grep, quoting, variable

I have a problem with escaped pattern put in `grep`.

My test file is:

```
export_cc = ${dir}/aaa/bbb/ccc
export_cc = ${dir}/aaa/bbb/eee
export_cc = ${dir}/aaa/bbb/ddd
export_cc = ${dir}/aaa/bbb/fff
export_cc = ${dir}/aaa/bbb/ggg
```

If I run:

```
~/programming/sandbox $ printf %q 'export_cc = ${dir}/aaa/bbb/ccc'
export_cc\ =\ \$\{dir\}/aaa/bbb/ccc
```

and then copy output to grep as the pattern I would get:

```
~/programming/sandbox $ grep export_cc\ =\ \$\{dir\}/aaa/bbb/ccc file
export_cc = ${dir}/aaa/bbb/ccc
```

But if I put pattern into the variable or backticks I would get:

```
~/programming/sandbox $ grep `printf %q 'export_cc = ${dir}/aaa/bbb/ccc'` file
grep: Trailing backslash
```

Could someone tell me why this makes the difference and how to use quoted string in variable as a `grep` pattern?

Comment: Show your desired output.

Comment: Desired output is the same as with putting pattern explicitly. When pattern is executed by expression in backticks grep fails and returns 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was [shell escaping](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_01). `\` is special character in shell, and also in `grep`.

In:

```
grep export_cc\ =\ \$\{dir\}/aaa/bbb/ccc file
```

`export_cc\ =\ \$\{dir\}/aaa/bbb/ccc` was interpreted by the shell to one string `export_cc = ${dir}/aaa/bbb/ccc` before passing to `grep`. You can use [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to check:

```
$ strace grep export_cc\ =\ \$\{dir\}/aaa/bbb/ccc file
execve("/bin/grep", ["grep", "export_cc = ${dir}/aaa/bbb/ccc",...
```

With [Command Substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03):

```
grep `printf %q 'export_cc = ${dir}/aaa/bbb/ccc'` file
```

Without double quote, the result of *Command Substitution* was [split and glob](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347/38906) by the shell into three parts: `export_cc\`, `=\`, and `\$\{dir\}/aaa/bbb/ccc`. The shell treated them as three strings, escape all backslashes and pass them to `grep` as `export_cc\\`, `=\\`, `\\$\\{dir\\}/aaa/bbb/ccc`:

```
$ strace grep $(printf %q 'export_cc = ${dir}/aaa/bbb/ccc') file
execve("/bin/grep", ["grep", "export_cc\\", "=\\", "\\$\\{dir\\}/aaa/bbb/ccc",...
```

`grep` received a pattern with one backslash `export_cc\` followed by nothing, and it shown the message `Trailing backslash`.

To make it works, you need to [double quotes command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/38906), and using [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) with `%s` instead of `%q`:

```
$ grep "$(printf %s 'export_cc = ${dir}/aaa/bbb/ccc')" file
export_cc = ${dir}/aaa/bbb/ccc
```

Comment: thank you very much for detailed answer, especially for mentioning strace which will help me with debugging shell commands.